# Convert SID to varbinary

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm usually using a user's AD account name as identifier when I make a web application and want to store user data. But since users leave and new users can get the same user name it has sometimes caused problems. So when creating a new web application I wanted to use the SID as identifier.
In the database (SQL Server) I've stored the SIDs as varbinary(85). In my web application I get the logged in user's SID as a string (SecurityIdentifier).

How do I convert this into a varbinary(85), to be able to query the database? Is that not possible in .NET Core 3.1?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.getbinaryform?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Principal_SecurityIdentifier_GetBinaryForm_System_Byte___System_Int32_

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class's own methods for this. [GetBinaryForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.getbinaryform?view=netcore-3.1) will write the SID's binary form to an existing array :

```
var myByteArray=new byte[85];
sid.GetBinaryForm(myByteArray,0);
```

Or you can use [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.tostring?view=netcore-3.1) to return its string form, eg `S-1-5-9` :

```
var stringForm=sid.ToString();
```