# How to get login name from SID in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which consists of SID String values (like S-1-5-21-). Is there a function which can give me the Login Name for all these SIDs?

**For example**:

```
SELECT [dbo].[ufn_GetLoginNameFromSID] 'S-1-5-21-1458884545-1705262899-650520445-1008965'
```

**Result**:

MyCompanyDomain\GaryBravos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would have replied to the first answer however dont have the rep yet :)

Try this:-

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME(SID_BINARY('S-1-5-21-1458884545-1705262899-650520445-1008965'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [SUSER_SNAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sname-transact-sql). For example:

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME('S-1-5-21-1458884545-1705262899-650520445-1008965');
```

Comment: Gave me an error "Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Comment: @GaryTheBrave https://stackoverflow.com/q/65125498/14868997 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/314072/220697

Answer (score 0):

That format looks like a Windows SID to me. This isn't a T-SQL solution, but a powershell one that I created a long time ago to track down recycle bin offenders.

```
param(
    [string] $sid = (Read-Host "Enter a SID")
)

$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ( $sid )
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] )
$objUser.Value
```